# How can I use multiple models to point to the same collection?

Tags: python, dynamic, mongoengine

I have a single collection that can represent multiple types of data:

```
class Taxes(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'taxes'}

    type = db.StringField() # State, local, federal
    owner = db.ReferenceField(User, unique=True)
    name = db.StringField()
    fiscal_year = db.IntField()
```

What I am wanting to do is have either a `DynamicEmbeddedDocument` or make this a `DynamicDocument` to hold different models.

For example:

```
class Taxes(db.Document):
    ...
    # This is made up syntax
    data = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(StateTaxes, LocalTaxes, FederalTaxes)
```

Or:

```
class Taxes(db.DynamicDocument):
    ...

class StateTaxes(Taxes):
    state_name = db.StringField()

class LocalTaxes(Taxes):
    locality_name = db.StringField()
```

The goal is to do this:

```
# Embedded Dynamic Document example
taxes = Taxes.objects(owner=current_user).all()
state_taxes = [tax.data for tax in taxes if tax.type == 'state']
state_names = [tax_data.state_name for tax_data in state_taxes]

# Dynamic Document example
taxes = Taxes.objects(owner=current_user).all()
state_taxes = [tax for tax in taxes if tax.type == 'state']
state_names = [tax.state_name for tax in state_taxes]
```

**Notes:**

- I must be able to perform 1 query to get back all types**.
- Models should be separate in order to allow for clean definitions.
- This example is very small, there would be a growing number of Models with very different definitions**.
- All Models will have 4 or 5 fields that are the same.
- The dynamic data should be relatively easy to query.

**These are the main reasons I am not using separate collections

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do models have to be separate exactly? I understand you have `Taxes` that occasionally need to store additional attributes. Why not just declare a simple extra field called `type` to store the fact that it is a state or a locality tax? Indeed, this is the line of thinking your desired code seems to belie.

Comment: IF you go that route, then you can do away with `EmbeddedDocumentField` in your class definition and instead simply set attributes dynamically. The [example in the docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#dynamic-document-schemas) would more than suffice for this sort of insertion.

Comment: From a OOP perspective `Taxes` is the base class for all of these models so even if I used multiple collections this would still serve as the base via multiple inheritance. The Models need to be separate because of how large they would be. Every model would have say 10 distinct fields. If I have 10 Models that 100 fields on a single object/class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a base class that covers all the base attributes (fields) and methods that you need. For example:

```
class BaseTaxes(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    value = db.IntegerField()

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

    def apply_tax(self, value):
        return value*(1+self.value)
```

With this base class you can then create different versions:

```
 class StateTaxes(BaseTaxes):
     state = db.StringField()
```

As such the StateTaxes class inherits both attributes of BaseTaxes and its methods (more details [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance)). Because it inherits the BaseTaxes class, it will be saved in the same collection (BaseTaxes) and queries can reach all subclasses:

```
 results = BaseTaxes.objects().all()
```

And then, to split results by subclass:

```
 state_taxes = [item for item in results if isinstance(item,StateTaxes)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and what I did!